# Como editar los colores cuando activamos el modo oscuro

Tags: android-studio, xml, app

No consigo modificar los colores que se muestran al activar el modo oscuro en el teléfono, entiendo que esto debe hacerse desde el archivo themes.xml(night) pero no consigo los resultados que deseo. Este es mi archivo themes.xml(night):

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.MiAppDark" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">

        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_200</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/black</item>

        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_200</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>

        <!-- Status bar color. -->
        <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>
</resources>
```

Caso 1: Si cambio `<item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/black</item>` a white se sigue mostrando de color negro, también he probado a cambiarlo a `<color name="teal_200">#FF03DAC5</color>`y no hay ninguna diferencia.

Caso 2: Si cambio manualmente por ejemplo la barra de botones a `<color name="teal_200">#FF03DAC5</color>`sí se muestra de color verde en ambos modos.

¿Existe alguna forma de cambiar esta configuración? y ya por último, ¿Por qué si copio el contenido del archivo themes.xml a themes.xml(night) se sigue mostrando igual que si no lo hiciera?

Este es mi archivo themes.xml:

```
    <!-- Primary brand color. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">#283593</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
    <item name="colorOnPrimary">#5A65FF</item>

    <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
    <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
    <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
    <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>

    <!-- Status bar color. -->
    <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">#5A65FF</item>
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
```

Espero que alguien pueda ayudarme, muchas gracias.

Comment: Hola Morodo, me parece que solo necesitas lo relacionado a uiMode, revisa mi respuesta, saludos.

Comment: tengo el mismo problema, necesito que la app no cambie los colores al entrar en modo oscuro, en el caso android:configChanges="uiMode" se debe declarar en el xml de cada activity o en que parte del proyecto?

Answer (score 1):

Para configurar el "modo nocturno" es importante que tengas otro archivo `themes.xml` pero este debe encontrarse dentro del directorio `/values-night`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Una razón por la cual no este cambiando el color al activar el modo nocturno es que te encuentres editando un archivo `themes.xml` que se encuentre dentro de `/build`, asegura que tu archivo se encuentre dentro de la ruta:

`app/src/main/res/values-night`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y lo más importante, tu `Activity` puede manejar el cambio de configuración de `uiMode`, define el atributo `android:configChanges="uiMode"`:

```
<activity
    android:name=".MyActivity"
    android:configChanges="uiMode" />
```

Cuando cambia el tema de la aplicación (ya sea a través de la configuración del sistema o AppCompat), se activa un cambio de configuración de `uiMode`. Esto significa que las actividades se volverán a crear automáticamente.

Revisa [Android: Cambios de configuración](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/darktheme#cambios_de_configuraci%C3%B3n)